# Is there a difference between using 部分 and just 分?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

I believe they both mean "part" or "section", but I see both of them being used in the same context.

Comment: Please give examples where you see them in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

部分 is a separate word, but 分 can be used along with some other word.
分 cannot be used as a separate word.

Example:
**use of 部分**

彼(例えば：John)の部分を送ってください。Please send his part.

**use of 分**

John分を送ってください。Please send John's part.

Comment: Did you mean `Johnの分`?

Answer (score 0):

- 「～の部分」：A part of something
- 「～の分」：Someone's share